# my php code related to ob_flush() & flush() sleep() working great on localhost but not on server

Tags: php, buffer, outputstream, flush

my this code is working great on localhost but not works on server I am using shared hosting I don't know another setting I have to change.

```
<?php
// Turn off output buffering
ini_set('output_buffering', 'off');
// Turn off PHP output compression
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', false);

//Flush (send) the output buffer and turn off output buffering
while (@ob_end_flush());

// Implicitly flush the buffer(s)
ini_set('implicit_flush', true);
ob_implicit_flush();
ob_start();
//$buffer = str_repeat(" ", 4096)."\r\n<span></span>\r\n";

for ($i=1; $i<7; $i++) {
  echo $i;
  ob_flush();
  flush();
  sleep(2);
}

ob_end_flush();

//phpinfo();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll often find with shared hosting providers that they turn off certain PHP functions for performance and/or security reasons. Check with your provider if they have any restrictions

Comment: can you tell exact all those settings which i have to ask them for on or off. because when i submit my ticket with my codes they replied they can't support for code. I have to tell them exact setting.